# How do I avoid a memory leak from a static fragment context?

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-context, android-memory

I keep getting a warning for a memory leak for my static fragment instance.
I declare it as follows:

private static myFragment thisFragment;

and call it here:

```
public static myFragment newInstance() {

        if (thisFragment == null) {
            thisFragment = new myFragment();
        }
        return thisFragment;
    }
```

How do I fix this? any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of holding a static reference to the fragment?

Comment: Just create a new fragment instance every time the method is called, like the method name suggests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there are 3 possible solutions:

1) Not creating static Fragments. They are always bound to the context, so, they shouldn't be static. Consider refactoring your app architecture.

2) Setting fragment instance to `null` when context is destroyed (activity onStop)

3) Using WeakReference for fragment field which will not hold the instance from GC.

**UPD:** Example for 3)

```
class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static WeakReference<Fragment> instance;

    public static ExampleFragment getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new WeakReference<>(new ExampleFragment());
        }
        return instance.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me examples of each with respect to my code, would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Hmm. I need more of your code to provide an examples for 1) or 2). But 3) is pretty trivial. Updated my answer

Comment: with regards to 2, onstop, i set thisfragment = null; , will that be sufficient?

Comment: Yep, every of that solution is enough :). Practically, when you set thisfragment to null you free the context and let GC to collect it

Comment: thats awesome, thanks so much, i like the weakreference usage. onstop is not guaranteed. Also, in my baseapplication file, I have another static variable with potential for leaks, some customconnection parameter, is it possible to set weakreference for that too and not just fragments?

Comment: Yep. WeakReference can hold any object. It just lets GC to collect them if only WeakReference holds the reference.

Comment: I also should ask you to check an architecture of your app. Holding fragment in static is realy the worst practice.

Comment: i have no idea why they decided to hold static reference, this wasn't my code and needed to be delivered asap. But i am hoping they had a valid reason for it. At this point changing the architecture could result in a on of issues. I try not to change things that arent mine :) thanks for the awesome answer though!

Comment: No problems :) Just remember for the future that there is no valid reason for such code. Have a goot time!

Comment: seems like that class is being used as a singleton.Is it still a good idea to use a weakreference with a singleton class?

Comment: Practically, you should check it in your application. It's good idea If it's ok for item to be collected when there is no other references to the instance except the static field.

Comment: so it should be fine ? The instance is being used in another place , would recreating it again affect performance or cause any other issues?

Comment: Fragment which is not attached to context returning null in getActivity(). That's the main danger.

Answer (score 1):

You should never ever ever ever EVER hold a static reference to a Context.

WHY do you need to hold a static reference to a fragment? If you answer that, then we can guide you on how to avoid it.

Static references never die, and that fragment context is most likely linked to an Activity context at some point, which means that ALL those elements can never ever be garbage collected. This is really bad.

Comment: Hm... holding fragment in static reference is absolutely bad. But holding context in static field may be safe if you use WeakReference or free the link in time. Also it's ok to hold application context in static